# Criar perguntas que não tenho dúvidas sobre é errado?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Recentemente tenho usado mais os sites do Stack Exchange que de costume, e num desses passeios pelo site "descobri" que a principal diferença do site para fóruns ordinários é a garantia de qualidade de respostas e perguntas. Ou seja, a pergunta não deve, propriamente, resolver o seu problema, mas generalizar de forma que outra pessoa possa resolver um problema parecido com sua dúvida.

Seguindo esta ideia, seria lógico criar perguntas interessantes e possivelmente comuns que não temos dúvidas apenas para acrescentar ao SE?

Comment: Já consta da documentação, e é incentivado pela rede, tanto que você ja tem a opção de numa postagem só já perguntar e responder (nos campos apropriados, claro) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer em especial este trecho: _"Para incentivar as pessoas a fazer isso, há uma caixa de seleção na parte inferior da página cada vez que você faz uma pergunta. Se você tiver mais de 15 pontos de reputação e já sabe a resposta, clique na caixa de seleção "Responder sua própria pergunta" na parte inferior da página Fazer uma pergunta. Digite sua resposta e envie a pergunta e a resposta juntas."_

Comment: E sobre eu deixar a pergunta em aberto? E deixar que outros respondam, tem alguma diferença para "me auto-responder"?

Comment: Aí já é outro cenário, mas tem bastante discussão sobre isto no meta, vale uma pesquisada. O que a gente recomenda é esperar um pouco para aceitar as respostas, assim dá tempo de surgirem alternativas até melhores que as que postamos. O que mais importa mesmo é a qualidade da pergunta, que é o que garante que seja possível uma resposta de qualidade, independente de serem do autor.

Comment: Só faço uma ressalva, garantia é um termo muito forte, temos bastante porcaria por aqui como qualquer fórum, só temos regras e cultura para que essa quantidade seja menor e ressalte o conteúdo de qualidade. Só tome o cuidado de que seja algo que realmente seja útil. Algumas pessoas tentam e quebram a cara poque não percebem que a dúvida não é tão comum e a resposta não é tão boa assim. Vale para só perguntar ou fazer par de pergunta e resposta. Uma quantidade grande de perguntas boas aqui foram feitas assim, mas a pessoa observou bem as regras e costumes. Exemplo: não postar algo já existente.

Comment: @Maniero "garante que seja possível", não garante que vai acontecer ;)